# Search for last changed files and added files C# vb

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm looking for a way to search for changed files/folders based on date criteria.

I've got a path with loads of folders in it. I want to search inside the main folder "C:\map" and see if there is anything changed or created after ex. 2015-01-01 (subfolders, files, etc.).

I was thinking about making a list of all the folders that are inside C:\mapp then search in them for changed files or subfolders. If something's older than 2015-01-01 I want to list the directory from the list. Not anything inside it. If there are files inside it that are newer don't do anything.

My idea was to build an .exe in Visual Studio and run it on my server.

Anyone got an idea, I'm a bit new to C# and VB :/

Comment: VBA <> VB <> VB.Net. (And now you've retagged with C#.) First make up your mind what language you're using.VBA only works  in MS Office applications, so it has nothing to do with Visual Studio. Next, search here for *Lang iterate files in folder* (replacing *Lang* with whatever language you're really using). That will get you started, and then you can come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you asking how to make a C# program to find changed files?

Comment: Yes. my idea is to make a program like that.

Comment: @ante011: Read [SCOPE and DIRECTORY Predicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231257(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you're just starting out, I'd start here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

That will get you iterating over a folder path.

Then learn to use the [fileinfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object in C# to get all the data for each file you encounter.  You can use it to find all the date fields on each file as you iterate through them.

You can follow the same process for VB or C# - I'm posting the C# links.  Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

```
public DateTime? GetLastWriteTimeOfDirectory(string path)
{
    return GetLatestFile(new DirectoryInfo(path))?.LastWriteTime;
}

private FileInfo GetLatestFile(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    if (!directory.Exists)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Directory {directory.FullName} does not exist.");
    }

    return directory.GetFiles()
            .Union(directory.GetDirectories().Select(d => GetLatestFile(d)))
            .OrderByDescending(f => (f == null ? DateTime.MinValue : f.LastWriteTime))
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

I search for that exact topic two weeks ago, and I saw some code here on stackoverflow. I copied it and adjusted it. So you pass a directory path, and it GetLatestFile will go to the directory and all it's subdirectories for getting the lastet file